# Subsets of $ \mathbb Q $ of order type $ \omega^{\alpha}$ for each countable ordinal $\alpha $.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, self-learning, order-theory, ordinals

My introductory text in Set Theory (Stillwell) includes an exercise (6.3.1) asking for an explicit example of a subset of $ \mathbb Q $ or order type $ \omega^2 $.  This seems straight forward enough.  I wish to generalize this, first by explicitly defining a sequence of sets $ A_n \subset \mathbb Q $ such that $ A_n $ has order type $ \omega^{n} $ and then seeing where we can go from there. (See **Details** below.)

Taking the $limsup \{A_n\}$, I believe we get $A_{\omega} = \cup A_n$.  While my intuition carries me through $A_n$ for finite $n$, it is not entirely clear to me what $A_{\omega}$ *looks like*, or indeed if $A_{\omega}$ has order-type $\omega^{\omega}$.  I think it does.  If so, we should be able to carry on to generate $A_{\alpha}$ for each countable ordinal $\alpha$.

> Is this correct?  This is self-learning, so I don’t have anyone to refer to.  What is a better way of doing this so that *intuition* holds up past $\omega^{\omega}$?

I am reading an introductory text but my question is more *intermediate* than *introductory*.  This is why I am unsure and seeking help.  For example, the text does not cover [set-theoretic limits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit).

---

---

**DETAILS**

This is what I have done so far :

First, let $A_1 = \mathbb N$. Clearly $A_1$ has order-type $\omega^1$.

To make clear my approach I shall write $A_2$ in *long hand*.$$A_2 = \{ 1 - \frac12, 1 - \frac13, 1 - \frac14, \dots, 2 - \frac12, 2 - \frac13, \dots \} .$$

To generalise, given $A_n$, write $A_n = \{ a_1, a_2, \dots \}$, where $a_n \lt a_{n+1}$.

Define $a_0 = 0$ and $d_i = a_i  - a_{i-1}$ for $i \gt 1$.

Next, for each $i > 0$, let $$B_i = \{ a_i - (d_i \cdot \frac{1}{k}) : k \in \mathbb N \}.$$
Finally, we define $$A_{n+1} = \cup_i B_i$$

Defining our $A_n$ in this way should mean $A_n$ has order-type $\omega^n$.  Does this extend to infinite ordinals?

Comment: Every countable ordinal is isomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb Q$. But there is no explicit example for most of them.

Comment: @azarel Yes, a later exercise asks us to prove this "indirectly".  I was trying to understand how far we can push an explicit isomorphism.  This seems correct for finite $ n $.  Is it not correct for $ n = \omega $ using the limsup?

Comment: $\bigcup_nA_n$ isn’t well-ordered. However, you can build a set isomorphic to $\omega^\omega$ by building a copy of $\omega$ in $[0,1)$ converging to $1$, a copy of $\omega^2$ in $[1,2)$ converging to $2$, etc.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Excellent.  That seems a much more clever approach than mine, and it also gives a reasonably clear picture of the resulting $ \omega^{\omega} $ ordering.  Thanks!

Comment: You’re welcome!